# Can not connect to MySQL with VS2012

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to establish connection between my application in C# and MySQL. I have downloaded .NET connector from MySql website.
I have installed MySQL server with TYPO3 winstaller, and it is running properly.

Here is my code:

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost:8501;Database=drogy;Uid=root;Pwd=;");
 con.Open();
```

It says that: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

In PHPMyAdmin I see host as localhost:8501. I am sure that user root has password set to NO and I am also pretty sure about the database name. How can I do this please? Thank you

Comment: This is most likely *not* a C# issue. Try to connect with the same connection settings with any tool to verify that you can actually connect to the database

Comment: I am wondering what TYPO3 has to do with that? If you need a MySQL server on your windows system you should install http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you should not mention the **`password`** if maybe its should be `empty` means use the `' '` **single quotes** in you code.
2. And you should remove the `;` in after the `password` like `ot;Pwd=;");` you should change like `ot;Pwd=");`
3. if your not add the connector, first of all you should must add the  `MySQL Connector`.

sample code:

```
"server=localhost:portno; user id=yourusername; password=yourpassword; database=yourdatabasename"
```

**update:1**

All had happend after moving database files to new location and after updating mysql server. All tables with InnoDB engine disappeared from my database. I was trying to recreate them, but mysql told me `1146: Table 'xxx' doesn't exist` all the time until I had recreated my database and **`restarted mysql service`**.

I think there's a need to read about InnoDB table binaries.

[**click here : 1**](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/security-admin/resolving-mysql-error-1146-table-doesnt-exist-when-doing-backup/)

Comment: I have this and it doesnt work: server=localhost:8501; user id=root; password=; database=dummy

Comment: Again I'm telling you, must mention the password

Comment: so should I type password=NO ?

Comment: `no` mean it empty or `no` is password,... you should read my answer in my first line

Comment: no means no password / empty. I am trying to create new user with password, but i am getting error in phpmyadmin: #1146 - Table 'mysql.procs_priv' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

**Pwd=;"**Required your database password
In the password field give your password and try it.. it will work